# How do I direct my awk command to work on column 2

Tags: awk

I would like this `awk` command to replace the last underscore of column 2 with a tab. As it is now, it replaces the last underscore in each line with a tab, note that each line may have a different number of underscores in the columns. I have tried many things to direct the command to work only on column 2. I know I am so close, can anyone do that final tweak?

Example file tab-separated:

```
OTU1 this_is_the_second_column 100 0 450 this_is_the_sixth_column 1 5 3.2
OTU2 this_is_another_column_to_parse 103 4 650 this_is_another_test_string_too 4 7 4.6
```

And what it should look like:

```
OTU1 this_is_the_second column 100 0 450 this_is_the_sixth_column 1 5 3.2
OTU2 this_is_another_column_to parse 103 4 650 this_is_another_test_string_too 4 7 4.6
```

Here is my current code:

```
gawk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"}{last=$NF;NF--;print $0"\t"last}' test1.tab > test1_reformat.tab
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Setting FS and OFS in the options *and* in BEGIN is not necessary. Setting them to different values is plainly wrong. If your fields are tab-separated, then both FS and OFS must (obviously) be tabs. Then you just need to find and fix the last "_" in $2.

Comment: What should the code do to $2 if it doesn't contain any `_`s - put a tab before it or after it or leave it as-is?

Comment: Using cut, past and sed might be an easier option in this case: cut -f1-2 -d ' ' <infile | sed 's/\(.*\)_/\1 /' | paste - <(cut -d ' ' -f3- <infile)

Answer (score 6):

Since you appear to have GNU awk, you could use its [gensub](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-gensub_0028_0029-function-_0028gawk_0029-1) function to capture a trailing sequence of non-underscores after an underscore and resubstitute it after a tab:

```
gawk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS="\t"} {$2 = gensub(/_([^_]*)$/, "\t\\1", "1", $2)} 1' test1.tab
```

Alternatively (and - I think - portably) use the `match` function with some string slicing:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="\t"} match($2,/_[^_]*$/) {$2 = substr($2,1,RSTART-1) "\t" substr($2,RSTART+1)} 1' test1.tab
```

Answer (score 4):

Here you go

```
gawk '
    BEGIN { OFS = FS = "\t" }              # Output as input as tabs
    {
        n = split($2, a, "_");             # Split $2 by "_" into array
        for(i = 1; i<n; i++) {
            s = (i>1 ? s "_" : "") a[i]    # Rejoin fields with "_"
        }
        $2 = s OFS a[n];                   # Join last with OFS
        print
    }
' file
```

Provided you remove the comments you can run this on a single line, but I wouldn't recommend that for production code.

Output from your example input (with tabs expanded as spaces due to formatting constraints here)

```
OTU1    this_is_the_second      column  100     0       450     this_is_the_sixth_column        1       5       3.2
OTU2    this_is_another_column_to       parse   103     4       650     this_is_another_test_string_too 4       7       4.6
```

Answer (score 3):

To not over complicate the solution. Here is one way to achieve of what you want

Let's say your input is as follows and stored in `infile` (I am adding another line just for demonstration purposes):

```
OTU1 this_is_the_second_column 100 0 450 this_is_the_sixth_column 1 5 3.2
OTU2 this_is_another_column_to_parse 103 4 650 this_is_another_test_string_too 4 7 4.6
OTU2 this_is_another_column_to_parse_and_parse 103 4 650 this_is_another_test_string_too 4 7 4.6
```

Then you could do something as follows:

```
awk -vOFS="\t" '{p = match($2, /_[^_]*$/); if (p) $2 = substr($2, 1, p-1) "\t" substr($2, p+1)}1' infile
```

The output:

```
OTU1    this_is_the_second  column  100 0   450 this_is_the_sixth_column    1   5   3.2
OTU2    this_is_another_column_to   parse   103 4   650 this_is_another_test_string_too 4   7   4.6
OTU2    this_is_another_column_to_parse_and parse   103 4   650 this_is_another_test_string_too 4   7   4.6
```

Answer (score 1):

Using perl:

```
$ perl -F"\t" -le 'BEGIN{ $, = "\t" };
                   $F[1] =~ s/^(.*)_(.*)/$1$,$2/;
                   print @F' test1.tab  
OTU1    this_is_the_second      column  100     0       450     this_is_the_sixth_column        1       5       3.2
OTU2    this_is_another_column_to       parse   103     4       650     this_is_another_test_string_too 4       7       4.6
```

- `-F"\t"` turns on perl's auto-split mode (similar to awk, but using an array called `@F` instead of $1, $2, $3, etc) and tells perl to split on tabs.  `-F` also turns on perl's `-n` mode, which makes it run like `sed -n`.  See `man perlrun` and search for `-F`, `-a`, and `-n`.

  Note that array indices in perl start from zero, so `$F[0]` is the first element, `$F[1]` is the second, etc.
- `$,` is perl's output field separator variable (documented in the `perlvar` man page). Setting it in a BEGIN block (`BEGIN{ $, = "\t" }`) ensures that it runs only once when the script starts, not once for every input line.
- `$F[1] =~ s/^(.*)_(.*)/$1$,$2/` changes the last `_` in the second field to `$,`. Regex matches in perl are greedy by default, so `^(.*)_` will match and capture everything before the **last** `_`.
- the `@F` array is then printed.

This is portable in that it'll work if you have any version of perl installed (i.e. doesn't require a non-standard version like GNU awk for `gensub()`)

---

Alternatively, using perl's `join()` function (see `perldoc -f join`) instead of setting `$,`:

```
perl -F"\t" -le '$F[1] =~ s/^(.*)_(.*)/$1\t$2/;
                 print join "\t", @F' test1.tab
```

---

Another alternative is to use the `splice()` function (see `perldoc -f splice`) to actually insert a new element into the `@F` array between fields 2 & 3 (which is not the same as the second element containing the field separator).  The new element becomes the third element (`$F[2]`) and the indices of all subsequent element are incremented by one.

This would be useful if you needed to do further processing on the array after the new field has been inserted (unlike awk, inserting or removing elements into/from an array is trivial as perl has array manipulation functions built-in)

```
perl -F"\t" -le '$F[1] =~ s/^(.*)_(.*)/$1/;
                 splice @F, 2, 0, $2;
                 print join "\t", @F' test1.tab
```

Worth noting: the capture groups from the `s///` substitution operator persist until they either go out of scope or until another regex match or substitution succeeds - which is why `$2` can be used with `splice`.

This also means that this version won't work correctly if `$F[1]` on any input line **doesn't** contain a `_` character (it will insert a third field containing $2 from the last successful match, or an empty field until the first successful substitution).  To handle that, you'd have to test if the substitution succeeded, e.g.:

```
perl  -F"\t" -le 'if ($F[1] =~ s/^(.*)_(.*)/$1/) {
                    splice @F, 2, 0, $2;
                  } else {
                    splice @F, 2, 0, ""; # insert empty field 3
                  };
                  print join "\t", @F' test1.tab
```

The other versions won't really work correctly either - they'll output lines with a variable number of tab-separated fields - ten fields when the second field contains an underscore, nine fields otherwise.

They're not safe to use unless either: 1. the second field is guaranteed to always contain at least one underscore; or 2. you don't need to care whether the output has nine or ten fields.

These versions could be fixed by appending the field separator to the second field if the substitution failed - e.g. something like this:

```
$F[1] .= $, unless $F[1] =~ s/^(.*)_(.*)/$1$,$2/;
```

or this:

```
$F[1] .= "\t" unless $F[1] =~ s/^(.*)_(.*)/$1\t$2/;
```

BTW, the awk versions in the other answers so far all have the same potential problem, i.e. they will also output a variable number of fields, depending on the contents of the second field.  It wouldn't be hard to fix them.